# Auto watching @mentions in Jira?

Tags: jira

From what I have read, there is no out-of-the-box solution to auto-create watches from @mentions in Jira.

Since there @mention triggers an email event, is there a way to add additional triggers in Jira or secondly, have an Outlook trigger create a new watch in Jira?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Outlook, but there is a workaround in Jira. Using JQL, you can add a small snippet to screen for your mentions in all tickets that you are not watching.

The exact snippet is available on the [Atlassian community forum](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Autowatch-User-Mentions/qaq-p/992804). I don't want to copy the snippet here since it is not mine.